# Hide grid and some values on y-axis in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am new to Grafana and made a time-invariant chart. For better optics I would like to remove

1. the Grid and
2. some (not all) values on the x-axis. I tried it with an override matching regex, but unfortunately it's not applying a space char or null or none or whatever.

[image]

Is there any solution for that? Sorry, I could not find any. I'd appreciate a hint.